# Text Color "difference" on Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make something "tricky" for my level of CSS.
I would like to scroll a text and then it is passing from different divs, it will invert its color according to the background of the div.

Here is what I have done so far, but I miss the thing how the color could change on the green div.

For example, stay black in the white area, and then, make a "difference" color on the green box.

https://codepen.io/tzoun/pen/wvoQYGP

From my search I think I will need something like these properties:

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
filter: invert(1);
```

But with no luck so far.

Does anybody know If I am on the right path? Or maybe there is an alternative way to do this?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] _in the question itself_. A link to an external resource is not enough.

Comment: blending mode only works inside a stacking context. The #inBox you provided is a sibling of the paragraph elements, so they can't mix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with `gradient`

```js
$("#container").mouseenter(function(e) {

  $(this).animate({
    scrollTop: $(
      'html, body').get(0).scrollHeight
  }, 2000);

});

$("#container").mouseleave(function(e) {

  $(this).animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: relative;
  
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%, rgba(3,145,3,1) 25%, rgba(3,145,3,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(3,145,3,1) 25%,rgba(3,145,3,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(3,145,3,1) 25%,rgba(3,145,3,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#039103',GradientType=0 );

  
  
}
p {
     mix-blend-mode: difference;
    filter: invert(1); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam dolorum fugit et officiis unde ex nemo libero aspernatur enim ut molestias veniam hic natus delectus est, soluta recusandae fuga maxime!</p>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work, but is it possible to have as a background not a gradient, but an image?
and the text will change according to the image colors?

Comment: This is scrolling everything - not scrolling the text through the fixed colored bits - is that what you want? I'd read your question as a requirement for the text to scroll through the green.

Comment: Sorry I lost you there.

I am trying to make the same effect as on the green box, but instead of green background the box will have an image as a background.
Is there any way that this could work?

Comment: Hi, this isn't my answer so I'll just say, yes, you can put in a background-image which is a url rather than a linear-gradient (or you can have several). Mu question is, do you want the text to scroll through the image (which it is doing in the code in your question) or do you want it to remain static within the image and move up/down the screen with it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
No I want the text to scroll through the image.
Although when I use image as a background it is not working, I am not sure what is going on